# Subclassing Path causes rendering issues

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I'm trying to draw `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Path` objects to a `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Canvas` control. These objects are configured in their own coordinate system, and transformed to the pixel-space coordinate system using the `Transform` property of the `Geometry` objects.

However, I'm getting some odd behaviour that I'm struggling to make sense of. Here is code that replicates the issue:

XAML

```
<Window
    x:Class="TransformRenderBug.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TransformRenderBug"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    
    SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged">
    <TabView >
        <TabViewItem Header="Blank tab"/>

        <TabViewItem Header="Drawing tab">
            <local:NumberSpace x:Name="NumberSpace" >
                <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Transform="{x:Bind Transform}"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
                <Path Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="1">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="0.9" RadiusY="0.9" Transform="{x:Bind NumberSpace.Transform}"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
                <local:NumberSpacePath Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="1">
                    <local:NumberSpacePath.Data>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="0.8" RadiusY="0.8" Transform="{x:Bind Transform}"/>
                    </local:NumberSpacePath.Data>
                </local:NumberSpacePath>
                <local:NumberSpacePath Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
                    <local:NumberSpacePath.Data>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="0.7" RadiusY="0.7" Transform="{x:Bind NumberSpace.Transform}"/>
                    </local:NumberSpacePath.Data>
                </local:NumberSpacePath>
            </local:NumberSpace>
        </TabViewItem>
    </TabView>
</Window>
```

C#

```
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private CompositeTransform Transform { get; } = new();

        private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            NumberSpace.SetTransform(Transform, args.Size.Width, args.Size.Height - 40);

            NumberSpace.Width = args.Size.Width;
            NumberSpace.Height = args.Size.Height - 40;
        }
    }

    public class NumberSpace : Canvas
    {
        public CompositeTransform Transform { get; } = new();
        public NumberSpace()
        {
            SizeChanged += (o, e) => SetTransform(Transform, ActualWidth, ActualHeight);
        }

        public static void SetTransform(CompositeTransform transform, double width, double height)
        {
            // Figure out the transform required for the shapes to fill the space
            double pixelScaleX = width / 2;
            double pixelScaleY = height / 2;
            transform.ScaleX = pixelScaleX;
            transform.ScaleY = pixelScaleY;
            transform.TranslateX = pixelScaleX;
            transform.TranslateY = pixelScaleY;
        }
    }

    public class NumberSpacePath : Path
    {

    }
```

This code produces a window with two tabs. The first is blank. The second has four concentric ellipses drawn on it which take their transforms from either the Window or the Canvas. The ellipses are drawn as either `Path` objects or `NumberSpacePath` objects. `NumberSpacePath` inherits from `Path` but adds and changes nothing.

The two outer rings draw and resize without issue. However, when the second tab is first switched to, the innermost black ring is not rendered. Switching back to the first tab and again to the second tab causes it to be rendered. Additionally, enlarging the window causes the innermost two rings to be clipped, like on the image below. Again, switching and returning tabs causes them to be rendered correctly.

What is going on? Why does subclassing `Path` make a difference?

[image]

Comment: Maybe a bug (looks like some change is cached in raw WinRT side, I wonder if it would do the same with C++/WinRT projection). You should report it to Microsoft. PS: you can work around it if you reset the geometries at each transform change, i.e. something like this `p1.Data = new EllipseGeometry { RadiusX = 0.8, RadiusY = 0.8, Transform = Transform }; p2.Data = new EllipseGeometry { RadiusX = 0.7, RadiusY = 0.7, Transform = Transform };` etc. seems it "resets" something

Comment: The local namespace URL may be the issue : xmlns:local="using:TransformRenderBug"

Comment: I reproduced and have escalated this. You can also report it by WindowsAppSDK [Issues](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues).

Comment: Thanks all, reported at https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/3404